# Why do I have a question ban after posting a well reccived question?

Tags: support, answers

I recently had a question ban, because I asked two poorly formulated questions. I waited until the ban had expired, and then asked another question. This was relatively well received, with quite a few upvotes and a good answer. I just came to ask another question, and now I've found that I've gotten another question ban. Why is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry you've had some trouble with your questions. This "question ban" thing is automated and cannot be altered by us moderators. It can only be changed if SE staff decides to change it, which, as far as I know, they never have and likely never will.

Here's the "report" on your questions:

[image]

That flag on your Oct 10 question was "very low quality", which is probably what put you over the edge. The previous two questions are what are really hurting your standing. They are both negative score and closed, with one deleted.

This question block ends in two days. I suspect that another one will be permanent ... I think it's a little harsh, but I have no control over it.

Here is some general information about it: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

As for *fixing* your existing questions, I think the Oct 10 one is fine, but it does have two close votes (five will close it). I've made my case for it in the comments, and will not undo a five vote closure. Your Sep 30 question is repairable, I think. Look through that document and *edit* to ask a specific question about a claim the paper makes. Then you can ask me, other mods, or 10K+ rep users to look at it before you undelete it (ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason)). If it's good, undeleting and gaining a few upvotes on it will go a long way to preventing further question blocks.